# how do I end/ remove ssh and is it a good idea to?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to make my system more secure and concerned it may have already been compromised.

As i do not need remote access, how do i disable ssh and would this cause problems for other processes?
As have not enabled ssh myself how would I first check it if is active please?

Comment: To check if SSH is running look at [this resource](https://cplusprogrammer.wordpress.com/2016/10/17/how-to-check-if-ssh-is-running-on-linux/)

Comment: Stopping (if running) and uninstalling, in this order: `ssh systemctl stop ssh` and `sudo apt remove openssh-server` would be secure enough for me.

Comment: is there a way to check if it is running first?

Comment: Yes: `sudo systemctl status ssh` will tell you if it's running or not.

Comment: "Unit ssh.service could not be found." Good I guess this means i don't need to disable anything?  thank you

Comment: This means you have no ssh server installed, so there is nothing to disable or uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

If the firewall won't let telnet nor ssh through - it shouldn't matter if they are enabled -

```
 sudo ufw delete allow telnet
 sudo ufw delete allow ssh
```

Comment: would these commands prevent anyone accessing my system remotely? this is what I am trying to stop be able to happen.

Comment: It's been my experience that these commands will knock out remote telnet and remote ssh as long as your firewall is up, which should be always if you are being security cautious.  I did verify the above disabled telnet prior to traveling with an Ubuntu laptop.

Comment: does ufw allow those both as standard? I mean you need to specify not to allow them?

Comment: telnet comes in on port 23 - that's what the telnet deamon is listening to .  Likewise ssn is on port 22 - that is the standard.  If you don't want to believe me - try it.  That's what I did and will do before leaving the house with my laptop.  I disallow telnet on the laptop then try to telnet into my laptop before taking the laptop elsewhere.